# Diferença entre date e datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, data, tipagem

Estava pesquisando sobre os tipo de dados do *SQL SERVER* e me deparei com essa [tabela](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186724(v=sql.120).aspx)

Qual seria a real diferença entre `date` e `datetime` de dados?
Apenas na notação de hora, minuto, segundo ?

O que seria essa coluna Precisão?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A diferença não é só a notação, é o conteúdo, é o valor que ele armazena. O primeiro não tem hora, só a data, o segundo tem ambos, e isso é importante porque é possível extrair só a data ou só a hora do segundo, mas o primeiro só tem data.

A precisão é justamente até que ponto ele consegue ser granular. Podemos pensar em quantas casas de dados ele possui, ou qual é o menor valor que ele consegue te informar. O menor valor de `date` é um único dia, não para para ir além disto. No `datetime` vai até um valor de 1 segundo dividido por 300, você não pode pegar 1 milésimo de segundo, por exemplo. Esta informação não está presente na coluna.

Obviamente que se você tem mais informação, ocupa mais espaço, conforme mostra a tabela.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

### Breve explicação sobre os tipos

Não é uma comparação tão simples assim.

O único ponto em comum entre  `Date` e `DateTime` é que os dois são usados para armazenar datas.

O tipo `DateTime` e `SmallDateTime` são tipos pré SQL Server 2008  (eles estão lá desde, pelo menos,  a versão 4.5NT, o primeiro Microsoft SQL Server) e muitos defendem que eles deveriam ser considerados Obsoletos ( e eles só estão lá por razões de retrocompatibilidade).

`DateTime` aloca sempre 8 Bytes, o horizonte de datas vai de 1753-01-01 à  9999-12-31 e o tempo com precisão fixa de nanosegundos com incrementos de  .000, .003, or .007 segundos, o por quê disso  eu vou demonstrar no final desta resposta.

`SmallDateTime` aloca sempre 4 Bytes, o horizonte de datas vai de 1900-01-01 à 2079-06-06 (se você acha que isso está longe, você está pensando igual aos programadores que conceberam o formato de data com o ano de dois dígitos que criaram o bug do ano 2000)  e o tempo com precisão fixa em segundos.

Com a necessidade de tornar o  SQL Server mais próxima do SQL Standard, foram incluídos os tipos `DATE`, `TIME`, `DATETIME2` e `DATETIMEOFFSET` à partir da versão SQL Server 2008.

Antes (do SQL Server 2008) você só podia armazenar datas incluindo o tempo, mesmo que este fosse sempre zero. *Aqui cabe um paralelo*: É o mesmo que armazenar Inteiros usando um tipo Decimal (float, double, etc..). Você pode, mas está desperdiçando espaço fazendo isso.

A partir do SQL Server 2008, quando há necessidade de armazenar somente Datas, sem o tempo, foi disponibilizado o tipo `DATE` que aloca sempre 3 Bytes (praticamente um terço do tipo `DATETIME`) e sua faixa vai de 1900-01-01 à  9999-12-31.

Quando você precisa armazenar somente o tempo foi criado o tipo `TIME` que aloca de 3 a 5 Bytes, dependendo da precisão escolhida. A precisão influencia na quantidade de dígitos de fração de segundos. Se 0 o horizonte de tempo vai de 00:00:00 a  23:59:59.  Se 7, 00:00:00.0000000 a 23:59:59.9999999.

O tipo `DateTime2` que é a união dos tipos `Date` e `Time` (e essa afirmação é verdadeira mesmo na forma em que o `DateTime2` é armazenado internamente), que aloca de 6 a 8 bytes dependendo da precisão da fração de segundos. Um horizonte de  1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 a 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999.

E para finalizar o `DATETIMEOFFSET` que é o tipo `DateTime2` mais um indicador de fuso horário. Isso era uma limitação dos MSSQLServers anteriores, forçando o desenvolvedor a usar um campo varchar, com isso perdendo acesso à todas as funções nativas para tratamento de datas, para armazenar datas e tempo no formato  ISO 8601 : YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]Z (UTC)

### Como os tipos são armazenados

Internamente, o tipo `datetime` é armazenado como duas palavras duplas (DWORD). A primeira palavra dupla  (DWORD mais significativa) é a quantidade de dias antes ou depois (se usado um valor negativo) da data base (1900/01/01). A segunda palavra dupla (DWORD menos significativa) indica a o quantidade de pulsos de clock (ticks) após a meia-noite. Cada tick é de 1/300 de segundo.

Se você converter um `datetime` em `binary(8)`, você vai ver exatamente como a informação é armazenada:

```
Select convert(binary(8),cast('1900-01-00 00:00:00.000' as datetime))
0x0000000000000000

Select convert(binary(8),cast('1900-01-02 00:00:00.003' as datetime))
0x0000000100000001
```

Podemos ver claramente que são duas DWORDs(4 bytes cada) :

```
00000001|00000001
```

a primeira palavra 0x00000001 que é destinada à data (quantidade de dias após 1900-01-01) e a segunda palavra 0x00000001 que determina a quantidade de ticks após meia noite , 00:00:00 (lembrando que cada tick 3.33333... milésimos de segundo).

Agora se você converter um `date` em `binary(3)` você pode ver que

```
Select convert(binary(3),cast('00010101' as date));
0x000000

Select convert(binary(3),cast('00010102' as date));
0x010000

Select convert(binary(3),cast('99991231' as date));
0xDAB937
```

Agora se você converter um `Time` (precisão de zero dígitos, por motivos de simplificação)  em `binary(4)` você pode ver que

```
Select convert(binary(4),cast('00:00:00' as time(0)));
0x00000000

Select convert(binary(4),cast('23:59:59' as time(0)));
0x007F5101
```

Note que tanto no caso no `Date` quanto no `Time` dado é armazenado do menor para o maior Byte, ou seja,  a informação é armazenada "[extremidade menor primeiro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_%28ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)".

Se voce inverter 0xDA B9 37 você obtém 0x37 B9 DA, que em decimal representa 3652058, ou seja, 9999-12-31 é exatamente 3652058 dias após 0001-01-01.

Mesma coisa para o `Time`,  0x7F 51 01 invertendo 0x01 51 7F, que em decimal representa 86399 segundos após 00:00:00.

Como eu disse anteriormente, `DateTime2` é a união de `Date` e `Time`, como podemos ver:

```
Select convert(binary(7),cast('0001-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime2(0)));
0x00000000000000

Select convert(binary(7),cast('9999-12-31 23:59:59' as datetime2(0)));
0x007F5101DAB937
```

Note que os 3 primeiros bytes mais significativos de 0x007F5101DAB937 é  0xDAB937 que corresponde a Data e que os bytes 0x007F5101 restantes correspondem ao Tempo.

### Conclusão

Não é correto comparar os tipos `DateTime` com `Date`, neste caso seria mais apropriado comparar `DateTime` com `DateTime2`.

Segundo vária fontes consultadas, se você usa MSSQL Server 2008+ use `DateTime2` ao invés de `DateTime`.

### Fontes

[Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a record](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/)

[SQL Server 2008 Date and Time Data Types](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1616/sql-server-2008-date-and-time-data-types/)

[How to Get SQL Server Dates and Times Horribly Wrong](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/)

[Datetime vs. Datetime2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/DateTime/134800/)

Comment: Mas você está usando um *cast*, não faz sentido o que está falando. Com uma conversão qualquer coisa pode ser válida se fizer do jeito certo.

Comment: Retirei o trecho que que mencionei o Cast. Realemente, não explica como funciona o armazenamento interno do tipo `date`, que ao contrário do que eu expliquei, não é a parte mais significativa de um `datetime` e nem segue o mesmo principio.

Comment: Acho que piorou, está dando um monte de volta pra justificar algo que não é assim. E acho que o detalhe da implementação não é importante aí para esta pergunta, mas peslo menos é uma informação extra.

Comment: @Maniero E agora?

Comment: Não vai ter solução, o problema não é o texto ou o exemplo, é a ideia toda de que é um número decimal.

Comment: Mas eu já retirei essa parte do numero decimal. Concordo que na primeira versão eu confundi uma "conversão de decimal para data" com "como o tipo datetime é armazenado"